# Code Igniter URL routing confusion

Tags: codeigniter

I have a slight issue. I have configured my default controller as :

```
c$route['default_controller'] = 'news';
```

so when I point my browser to http://localhost/mysite all the news get loaded as instructed by the news controller. 
Now on this page, I have given links to "read article" to read the full article. For this I have to point my browser to http://localhost/index.php/news/view/news-slug. I want to remove index.php from the url. I had already tried re-routing using wildcard without any success. Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

There is a documentation on removing the `index.php` from the URL if you are using Apache with it's `mod_rewrite`:

- [Removing the index.php file](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Using the following rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also, there are many similar questions to yours, have a look at these questions from the search:

- [Search query on removing index.php in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+index.php+codeigniter)

Comment: I have folloed your links and discovered that mod rewite was not enabled in my apache server. This was one reason for getting an error on using htaccess. But my orignal problem is not yet solved. I still have to include index.php in the complete url when I have to pass variable for slug.

Comment: You cannot rewrite the URL without passing it with the `mod_rewrite`, I suggest you to enable it on your server.

Comment: I have mentioned that I have enabled mod rewrite for my apache server, but still the problem persist. I could not figure out exactly where to put my .htaccess file. Coz I am using WAMP and the whole thing screws up when i place it in the root directory.

Comment: Place it in the root of your Codeigniter directory, where you see `application`, `system`, etc - place the .htaccess file in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your .htaccess file for this. Check this wiki: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite